# Can't include MPIR library

Tags: c, gmp, mpir

I want to run a program, the compiler is crashing on the fact that it doesn't recognize the mpir.h include. I have used vcpkg to install mpir and did the vcpkg install integrate, to integrate it with Visual Studio. The program was normally with the gmp.h lib, but I can't run this on a Windows based system.

How can I include this w/o any errors or how can I run  this code with the gmp.h library?

`#include <mpir.h>`

This is the code I want to run:
https://cme.h-its.org/exelixis/web/software/tc/index.html

Comment: Did you install MPIR library?

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't it automatically installed when I use vcpkg package manager and run vcpkg install integrate (makes IntelliSense detect the installed libraries)

Comment: Make sure that it is installed and make sure that the include paths are set.

Comment: Could you try to run the program on a Windows-based system? To see if it works, otherwise I might have to run it on Ubuntu.

Comment: If you are doing serious science you should not use Windows. I believe all Exelixis Lab software is meant for Linux or MacOS, that's why they include `gmp.h` not `mpir.h` (MPIR is [not being supported](http://groups.google.com/group/mpir-devel?hl=en) for many years now). Also, their papers present results of software run on both these systems, couldn't find one which is run on Windows. You can for instance use the Linux Subsystem on Windows (I found out it works pretty well with GMP), or a virtual machine like VirtualBox, or just install Linux on your drive and you'll be fine.